# How can I update bootstrap version in Compass.app?

Tags: compass-sass, compass, bootstrap-sass

I'm using Compass.app GUI application on windows. By default I am having options to create new project with bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.1. How can i update this to bootstrap-sass 3.3.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put bootstrap-sass-3.3.6 folder in:

Windows:

```
compass.app/lib/ruby/compass_extensions
```

OSX:

```
compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_extensions
```

Compass will look automatically for the highest available version, you can leave previous version in compass folder.